# Problem with screen concurrency

Tags: gnu-screen

I am encountering a couple of issues while usage of screen. I am using PuTTY

Let's say, I am attached to a screen and execute the command

```
ls -la
```

Assuming the output covers my entire screen, I then issue

```
vim a.txt
```

After quitting VIM, I don't see the result of the previous `ls` command which is **unlike what I observe when I am detached from screen**.

Also any command that has a long output, on scrolling up through a mouse is lost. I use the `Ctrl+a+Esc` combo to go into copy mode and then scroll, using arrow keys (*mouse scroll fails here as well*). Is there any faster alternative to do that ?

Screen version 4.01.00devel (GNU) 2-May-06

Linux 3.13.0-139-generic #188-Ubuntu

Comment: When you use screen the scrool behaviour changes, have you try to use CAPS + Page up and Caps+ Page down to scrool inside screen ?

Comment: @Kiwy those key combinations don't work for me.

Comment: @Kiwy might have a special keyboard binding.  The native one is `^a`, `[` to enter copy mode, in which you can scroll through the `screen` terminal's backlog.

Comment: @DopeGhoti Thanks for that. It is almost at par with my choice for entering copy mode. Any idea on what might be happening for the first part to my question ?

Comment: If memory serves, programs such as `vim` that "preserve" the state of the screen as you describe use terminal control characters to present an alternate display layout for the application itself, which is switched back from when the application is terminated.  However, `screen` itself is already using this functionality, so it is not available to other programs like `vim` to use.

Comment: @DopeGhoti So do you mean that there's no workaround to this issue ?

Comment: Well, one workaround would be to open a new terminal within screen (`^A`, `^C`), run `vim` in there, and use `^A`, `^A` to toggle back and forth as desired.

Answer (score 0):

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49277886/1851678) works for me as of now. It essentially is

> Type `Ctrl-A+:` then `altscreen on<enter>`. You may add this to your ~/.screenrc file to make it persist.